# Php for loop, 2 times same id, randomized

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a memory game but I came uppon this problem where I can’t loop through all the images with 2 times the same id, so 2x id1, 2x id2 2x id3 etc. Also the id's need to be randomly assigned to the images.

**The PHP:**

```
class Kaart
{
    public function getCard()
    {
        for ($x = 1; $x <= 16; $x++) {
            echo "<img src='img/card_back.jpg' id=RANDOMID>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about [`rand()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.rand.php)

Comment: Create an array containing all the IDs 2 times. Shuffle the array.

Comment: You should not have duplicate IDs - perhaps use `data-id` instead?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the `Kaart` object, this creates a deck by merging two lists of the number range you pass in ( merging two ranges - `range(1,$count)`) and then shuffles the deck.

Then displaying the cards just means looping over the shuffled deck...

```
class Kaart
{
    private $deck = null;

    public function __construct( $count )   {
        // Create list with 2xid's
        $this->deck = array_merge(range(1,$count), range(1,$count));
        // randomize the deck
        shuffle($this->deck );
    }
    public function getCard()
    {
        // Loop over the randomized dech
        foreach ( $this->deck as $card )    {
            echo "<img src='img/card_back.jpg' id='{$card}'>";
        }
    }
}

// Create deck with 2x8 cards
$deck = new Kaart(8);
$deck->getCard();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_chunk` to randomized same id with 2 times.

```
 $img = [];
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 16; $x++) {
        $img[] = $x;
    }
    $i=1;
    foreach( array_chunk($img, 2, true) as $k => $array){
        foreach($array as $val){
            echo "<img src='img/card_back.jpg' data-id=".$i.">"; 
        }

        $i++;
    }
```